# Switch to page template when using post permalink

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages, templates

I'm new to wordpress development so hopefully I'm asking this right. The company I work for recently bought a custom wordpress site from an agency, but before we were able to launch it, the agency dissolved and we were left without any support and a lot of questions.

One of the issues is, we have a custom post type called "program", which is displayed in a page template: template-program.php. The specific program post is called in the template with a query string in the url like this: ourdomain.com/program/?program-id=1234. The problem is the url isn't pretty and our marketing team is worried this will have a negative impact on SEO. We tried using the post permalink instead of that query string like this: ourdomain.com/program/specific-program-post-slug, but it opens the single.php post template instead of template-program.php.

I understand the concept of WP template hierarchy but I'm wondering, is there a way to tell wordpress to use the page template we want when using the program post permalink? We tried copying the page template into a post template like, single-program.php, but the problem is a lot of the functionality built into the original template hinges on the fact that it's a page, not a post, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->permalinks and chose the permalink structure you want.
After that, update the .htaccess file with the content provided at the bottom of the page.